# How to show custom widgets included in UI forms?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt-designer

Qt Creator lets users promote `QWidget` instances to a custom class.  However, promoting a `QWidget` instance to a custom widget (i.e., a Qt form class that inherits `QWidget`) doesn't get Qt Designer to render that widget in the UI's layout.  Is there a way to get Qt Creator to render a custom widget as part of the widget that includes it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can provide a Qt Designer plugin along with your custom widget class, as explained in [Creating Custom Widgets for Qt Designer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-creating-custom-widgets.html) .

This is not easy, but you will end up with your custom widget shown in the designer toolbox.

One of the hardest parts: plugins have to be built with the same compiler used to build Qt Creator, which generally leads to downloading creator sources and build your own version.